# Re-orderable multi-selection widget for Plone, z3c.form and Dexterity

Tags: plone, dexterity, z3c.form

Plone 4.1b. Managed to get schema.List work correctly with CheckBoxFieldWidget.

Now I hope I could reorder the contents of the schema.List somehow.

Does there exist anything like "orderable multi-selection widget" for z3c.form / Plone / Dexterity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uh oh. Looks like the default widget for schema.List allows ordering, doing exactly what I was asking.